# should I upgrade the version to 1.9 or should I write a custom extension?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, extensions

I am new to magento and using *magento 1.7* .A custom theme is used currently which is not showing any features of a configurable product.

I tried to add the configurable product but it doesn't show up in the front-end like a configurable product would show with its features (user select option, corresponding price,image etc.).

I got to know that magento 1.9 version has this feature which can be easily handled.  So I am confused. What should I do ?

- Should I upgrade the version ?   or
- should I spent time towards writing an extension which will fulfill the requirement of a configurable product ?

Answer (score 3):

Magento by default will show a configurable products with all of it's option. Ideally, after a theme installed, it will not interfere this basic functionality. A theme just gives a site new look, that's it.

If you are not seeing configurable product options with your current theme, then which is indeed a problem of that theme and you need to contact the developer of theme for that.

So the whole point is

- Configurable product options will be shown in frontend irrespective of any Magento version.
- No need to upgrade the version for this sake. But upgrading to newer version is recommended since it gives more stability and security. If your site is highly customized and you're sure that it is going to be big panic if do an upgrade, then better leave as it is.
- No need for an extension, since it is a default feature in Magento.
- This is a theme issue and hence immediately contact the developers.

Comment: You are right @Rajeev . It is the theme issue. I have used a free extension called "color-switcher"( http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/color-switcher-free.html). But it only changes the image when selecting from the drop down. It doesn't affect to the price and tierprice of the product. I know I have to modify this extension but please guide me where and what to modify for the pricing related issue. So that when I select from dropdown it will change both its image and prices.

Comment: please contact the developer of that extension in that case. we are helpless in this case.

Comment: No problem @Rajeev. I will handle it. But could you please give me an overall Idea (work flow) like what happens when the dropdown option is selected (By default).

Answer (score 2):

This would do the Trick for for you

https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher

Credits @Marius

Answer (score 1):

You should write a custom extension or find out if the same extensions is already available on [Magento connect](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=magento+connect&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&gfe_rd=cr&ei=0p9WVs6vK-KK8Qe_1oKACA&gws_rd=ssl)

Upgrading magento may have some issues like

- Third party extensions you used in your website may not be compatible with magento 1.9